# django choice field returning index but not actual name

Tags: django, django-models

my **models.py**

```
class WebFieldType(models.Model):
    WEBFIELD_CHOICES = ( ('FACEBOOK', 'fb'), ('INSTAGRAM', 'Insta') )
    webfield_type = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=30, choices=WEBFIELD_CHOICES)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.webfield_type)


class WebTokens(models.Model):
    token_name = models.TextField()
    web_field_type = models.ManyToManyField(WebFieldType)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.token_name,self.web_field_type )
```

Now in shell if I do like:

`WebFieldType.objects.all().values('webfield_type')`, it is returning `[{'webfield_type' : 'FACEBOOK'}, {'webfield_type' : 'INSTAGARAM'}]`

But if I do like 
`WebTokens.objects.all().values('token_name','web_field_type')` it is returning

`[{'token_name' : 'some_token_name', 'web_field_type' : 1}]`

As you can see in web_field_type it is returning id, but I need name.
Even tried using return `'{}'.format(self.get_webfield_type_display())` in WebTokens model but in vain.

So basically I need everything that is stored in WebTokens model when I make a call to it.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what is `template_name` attribute in the `WebTokens` model. But I'll try to get your point. What are doing is that you take the values from ManyToMany field which is in your case `web_field_type: 1`. So if you want to get all vallues from the model and serialize it, then it would be more complicated than this. Consider creating method in `WebTokens` model.

**EDITED**

```
@property
def web_field_type_types(self):
    names = list()
    for obj in self.web_field_type.all():
        names.append(obj.get_type_display())
    return str(names)
```

And then using it in your queries so you can get string of ids with

```
webtoken.web_field_type_types
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake it's not self.template_type but it is self.web_field_type. I don't need the id's but i need the display name as output, example output :[{'token_name' : 'some_token_name', 'web_field_type' :'INSTAGARAM' }] but not as  [{'token_name' : 'some_token_name', 'web_field_type' : 1}]

Comment: it is giving property object, isn't there any other way where when I do the WebTokens.objects.all().values('token_name','web_field_type') it returns the :[{'token_name' : 'some_token_name', 'web_field_type' :'INSTAGARAM' }] .?

Comment: @newbie Yes there is but do you really web_field_type to be `ManyToManyField`, not just `ForeignKey`?

Comment: yes, because web_tokens have various combinations with web_field_type. Moreover I will have to add one more manytomany field similar to web_field_type which will also have choice field. So, please suggest a solution keeping this into account. In real scenario, what I'm doing is , I have a view where when we call that view, its returns all the values of WebToken model.